# 1 Button 2 activity in android studio using java

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

How do I open another activity with the same button I clicked earlier? For example, I click button A and goes to Activity 1 and I click home and click button A again and must go to Activity 2.

I tried putting id on button in xml and call different activity on its java.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine if the button is from HomeActivity,let the launcher activity pass an ExtraKey to the HomeActivity and again another ExtraKey at the **OnBackPressed** of the Activity you are navigating to after clicking the button.Set the onClickListner according to the String passed by those activities.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).